# String similarity algorithm (c++)

Tags: c++, algorithm, strings

Parameters:

`first` - the first string.
`second` - the second string.
`similarCharacters` - outputs the number of similar characters.
`tolerance` - the number of mistakes allowed to consider the strings "similar."

Function:

```
bool Str_Similar(std::string first, std::string second, unsigned int* similarCharacters = nullptr, int tolerance = INT_MIN)
{
    // Don't even check if either strings are empty.
    if(first.empty() || second.empty()) return false;

    // Determine if the first is greater than or equal to the second.
    const bool firstGreaterOrEqualToSecond = first.length() >= second.length();

    // By default, set the tolerance to half the length of the smaller string.
    if(tolerance == INT_MIN) tolerance = (firstGreaterOrEqualToSecond ? (second.length() / 2) : (first.length() / 2));
    if(tolerance < 0) tolerance = 0;

    // Start off with any length difference, which are considered mistakes.
    unsigned int mistakes = (unsigned int)abs(first.length() - second.length());
    // Search only the length of the smaller string.
    const size_t searchLength = (firstGreaterOrEqualToSecond ? second.length() : first.length());

    // Do the search.
    for(size_t i = 0, max = searchLength; i < max; i++)
    {
        if(first.at(i) != second.at(i)) mistakes++;
    }

    // Output the similar characters.
    if(similarCharacters != nullptr) *similarCharacters = (unsigned int)abs(searchLength - mistakes);

    // Compare the mistakes to the tolerance.
    return (mistakes <= tolerance);
}
```

Comment: @OliverYasuna I also provided a [compiling version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5358391209807f5). May be you should use that one to be reviewed.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My bad, I misunderstood you. Thank you for the suggestions. Anything else you could suggest? Please post that here so I can consider it solved, unless another, more detailed response is posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1. Prefer passing parameters by `const` reference

The `std::string` parameters should be passed by `const` reference rather than by value.

Even if passing by value would work properly, it makes the function signature clearer for the caller semantically and may be more efficient.

### 2. Fix all warnings

The line

```
return (mistakes <= tolerance);
```

results in a compiler warning:

```
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

### 3. Prefer to use `numeric_limits` over the C-style `INT_MIN`

For C++ code you should prefer to use `std::numeric_limits<int>::min()` instead of the `INT_MIN` macro (I couldn't even get that to compile, though `stdint.h` was included).

### 4. Always use `{}` braces for conditional code sections

You always should use braces to enclose conditional code sections

```
if(similarCharacters != nullptr) {
     *similarCharacters = (unsigned int)abs(searchLength - mistakes);
}
```

Not only it improves the readability of the code, omitting the braces may make the code error prone for changes.

---

My compiling version can be found [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a5358391209807f5).

Comment: 1) I passed them by value because I added code to the function which modifies these values. 2) Good point. 3) Thank you, my mind is still in C mode.

Comment: @OliverYasuna Sorry, I've been overlooking that was intended in your case.

Comment: Not your fault. I originally had posted the full function, which used the value strings, and forgot to change them after editing.

Comment: @OliverYasuna As CodyGray already mentioned, what you had there won't work properly.

Comment: `INT_MIN` is of course in `<climits>`, not `<cstdint>`.